# An infinite average of converging-to-zero sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider $S_n = (a_{1,m}+...+a_{n,m})/n$, where $m=f(n) \rightarrow \infty $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty $ for some $f$.

Also, for each $t=1,2,...$, we have $a_{t,m} = a_{t,f(n)} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Then, can we deduce that $S_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: Have you tried constructing a counterexample? Think of $\{a_{t,m}\}$ as a big table; each row is a sequence that approaches $0$, and $S_n$ is the average of the first $n$ entries in the $n$th column. What could you do to prevent $S_n$ from approaching $0$?

Comment: Yes, I can immediately contruct a counterexample. But, my question is actually just some rough simplification of something that is related to Parseval's identity and the Karhunen-Loeve representation in functional analysis. I am now too much lost in some specific algebra and have difficulty in looking at the whole problem from a wider viewpoint. Anyway, thanks for a comment. I might change the questions a little bit.